# Find a continuous $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ with range $f(\mathbb{R}) = \mathbb{Q}$

Tags: real-analysis

The given solutions are that this is impossible, due to the fact that by preservation of intervals, $f(\mathbb{R})$ must be an interval.

I don't really understand this reason, what does it mean? Why can't we use a constant function here, for instance $f = 4$ ?

Comment: Well, then $2\notin f(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: Ah, wait. So $f(\mathbb{R}) = \mathbb{Q}$ means it requires some domain to be mapped to the entire $\mathbb{Q}$ and $f(\mathbb{R}) \subset \mathbb{Q}$ doesn't suffice?

Comment: Yes, $f(\mathbb{R}) = \mathbb{Q}$ means every rational number is in the image, and only rational numbers are in the image.

Comment: got it. thanks daniel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the range contains infinitely many elements (all the rationals) then it contains at least two elements.
If $f$ is continuous and its range contains at least two elements $y_1<y_2$ (rationals or not) then, by the intermediate value theorem, the range contains all the interval $[y_1, y_2]$ which contains both rational and irrational numbers infinitely many times each. So, you cannot avoid irrational numbers in the range and the function you are looking for does not exist.